# wp_insert_posts add title with count of posts plus one

Tags: posts

I'm trying to create posts where title will be `1`, `2` etc,

```
$published_posts = wp_count_posts('orders')->publish;
$count = $published_posts + $a;

$success = get_page_link(794);

if(wp_mail($admin_email, 'Заказ с сайта: '.get_bloginfo('name'), $message)) {
    $my_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $count,
            'post_type'     => 'orders',
            'post_content'  => $message,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
        );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

but the title of post anywhere  is `1-2`, `1-3` etc.

How can I count posts and add post plus 1? For example, if the post is `10`, the name of new post will be `11`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I can't get `wp_count` of my custom post type. The result was that I got nothing.

I found this solution

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'orders'
);
$count = new WP_Query( $args );
$orders = $count->found_posts +1;
```

After this I insert my post